# Using javascript and regEx in order to replace a path of an emoji by its unicode

Tags: javascript, regex

I am facing a problem concerning replacing an emoji path with it's unicode. I want to use the RegEx functionality.
What I mean is that I want to replace :

```
teststring<img src=":/new/emoji/emoji/emoji-E057.png" />thanks<img src=":/new/emoji/emoji/emoji-E415.png" />
```

with

```
teststring\uE057thanks\uE415
```

Note that \uE057 and \uE415 are 2 unicode characters.
Anyone can help me with this issue.

Best Regards.

Comment: Neither `U+E057` nor `U+E415` are valid Unicode characters. Please explain these values.

Comment: @Tomalak they are private use area characters. Free for any font to use custom glyphs for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = 'teststring<img src=":/new/emoji/emoji/emoji-E057.png" />thanks<img src=":/new/emoji/emoji/emoji-E415.png" />',
    div = document.createElement("div"),
    imgs,
    regex = /emoji-([a-f0-9]{4})\.png$/i;

div.innerHTML = str;

imgs = [].slice.call( div.getElementsByTagName("img") );

for( var i = 0; i < imgs.length; ++i ) {
    var m = imgs[i].src.match(regex);

    if( m ) {
        imgs[i].parentNode.replaceChild(
            document.createTextNode(
                String.fromCharCode(parseInt(m[1], 16))
            ), 
            imgs[i]
        );
    }
}

var result = div.innerText || div.textContent || "";
//"teststringthanks"
```

Comment: The OP did not even say "jQuery". ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak I used it just to make the answer shorter and bearable to write and read. If I use normal DOM apis should I worry about cross browser stuff? You can't win and it would require a page of code. Think of it as pseudo code.

Comment: @Tomalak turned out to be "only" twice as long :P

Comment: I've implemented the exact same function. :-) Only trouble is that the hex codes the OP uses are no real Unicode code-points. Not sure what you need the `[].slice.call` and `innerText || textContent` bits for, though.

Comment: One more problem,
when I try to run my Qt project using this function written in my .js file, It gives me the following error:

Error: Invalid write to global property "document"
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: document

So I don't think I can write "document" in my code.
Any other solution ?